# Easy copy option for every code block

Tags: feature-request

I wish there's an easy option to copy rather than manually selecting(clicking and dragging) the code from the answers inputted by different users to a given question, something like the ones on GeeksForGeeks page.

```
Assuming this block contains code               (copy option here to copy the entire code in this snippet)
```